# Vim - zt will redraw the window with the cursor at the top. Can you redraw with it say, 4 lines down?

Tags: vim, window, redraw, text-cursor

Reading the manual with ':help z' shows a variety of commands which can redraw the window, e.g. <kbd>z.</kbd>to redraw with the cursor in the centre or <kbd>zb</kbd> to redraw with it at the bottom of the screen.

<kbd>zt</kbd> is nice but I would find it much more comfortable to be able to redraw with the cursor 25% of the way down the page (so that what I was just writing is still visible). Is there an easier way to accomplish this other than macro-ing it?

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you're looking for, but you can use `set scrolloff=n` (where n is some number of lines) to keep a specified number of lines always visible above the cursor at the top and bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `'scrolloff'` option:

```
set scrolloff=4
```

See `:help 'scrolloff'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the mapping (assigned to `<Leader>zt`) I use to put a number of lines above the cursor line at the top of the window:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>zt :<C-u>exec 'normal! ' . v:count . 'kzt' . v:count . 'j'<CR>
```

If you don't supply a prefix, it will put the line above the cursor at the top of the window.

Comment: You can consider using `<C-y>` in the mapping, too.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @echristopherson 's answer, this mapping should work, too:

```
nnoremap zt zt3<C-y>
```

and for the default behaviour:

```
nnoremap zT zt " 3<C-y> is not applied because of the n`nore` map.
```